# Laravel Pass Variable with HTML content to Email View

Tags: php, laravel, email

I think I'm doing something worng.

I'm trying to pass a variable into an Email View. This varaibvle is read from the database and is configurable via administration page. For some reason, I'm getting the emails without the HTML paser (I see tags like  in them) I wanted them to be parsed, so my client can manually change them everytime he wants.

How is that achievable?

My code is:

```
 Mail::send('emails.contact', array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'user_message' => $request->get('message'),
        'email_content' => html_entity_decode($emailContent->Description)
    ), function($message) use ($result)
    {
        $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'));
        $message->to($result['From'], $result['Name']);
        $message->subject('[Casa Bordeira] We received your message');
    });
```

An in the view:

```
<div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
  <div class="contentEditable" align='left' >
    <p>
        Hello <strong>{{$name}}</strong>. 
        <br/>
        {{$email_content}}
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Here's a copy of your message:
        <br/>
        <br/>
        {{$user_message}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blade has two different tag styles.

1. `{{ $string }}` - this will escape the content using HTML entities.
2. `{!! $string !!}` - this does not escape the content and will output the raw HTML value.

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I saw soimething like that on the web but totally misread that. Thank you again, and I should be more careful next time when searching.

Comment: Remember not to use $message, because it is a reserved variable, use her with mail will throw error.

Comment: If I have an html table inside $msg and need to insert some requests, it causes security issues or not?